# Validating an XML against an XSD using Apache Camel

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, apache-camel, xmlschema

My aim is to read a CSV file, convert it to an XML and validate it against an XSD. Below is the code:

```
    CamelContext _ctx = new DefaultCamelContext(); 
    _ctx.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data-sample.csv")
            .process(new MyTransformValidator())
            .to("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=emp.xml")
            .to("validator:src/main/resources?fileName=SampleXMLStructure.xsd");                
        }
});
```

Error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
>   route1 at: >>>
>   To[validator:src/main/resources?fileName=SampleXMLStructure.xsd] <<<
>   in route:
>   Route(route1)[From[file:src/main/resources?fileName=data-sam...
>   because of Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   validator://src/main/resources?fileName=SampleXMLStructure.xsd due to:
>   Failed to resolve endpoint:
>   validator://src/main/resources?fileName=SampleXMLStructure.xsd due to:
>   There are 1 parameters that couldn't be set on the endpoint. Check the
>   uri if the parameters are spelt correctly and that they are properties
>   of the endpoint. Unknown
>   parameters=[{fileName=SampleXMLStructure.xsd}]

Also,I would like to configure if some Exception occurs if the XML is not valid for the given XSD. How do we configure this?

Please kindly help.

Comment: See bottom of the validator documentation page on how to validate XML: https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/validator.html

Comment: the examples are in JAVA and XML DSL not in the format which I am looking for. Please help as I am really stuck in this issue and not able to move forward.

Comment: Please be focused. Ralf correctly gave you reference to Camel documentation(not to JAVA documentation). Before using any Camel component please read about it. And if you will read  about validator component you will see that your example is not correct, that's why you got an error. Validator component haven't fileName property and it is written in exception. See examples in documentation, configure it correctly and try again.

Comment: May be this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28263085/how-can-i-validate-xsd-using-apache-camel

Comment: I just changed validator code to: `.to("validator:file:src/main/resources/SampleXMLStructure.xsd");` The Error is gone now. The program runs but when the XML is not confirming to the XSD no error is shown. I need to have some exception block that would show the exception. Please help me with my code above.

Comment: Seems you are confusing the validator component with the bean-validator or json-validator components. Those you use with `to("...")` as a route step. But not the validator component, as per documentation.

Answer (score 0):

With exception block try like this:

```
from("file:src/main/resources?fileName=data-sample.csv")
            .process(new MyTransformValidator())
            .to("file:src/main/resources/?fileName=emp.xml")
            .doTry()
            .to("validator:file:src/main/resources/SampleXMLStructure.xsd")
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .log(LoggingLevel.WARN, "Failed validation cause:${exchangeProperty.CamelExceptionCaught}")
            .process(exchange -> {
                Throwable exception = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);
                // process exception
            })
            .end()
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Finished processing file");
```

Comment: I tried the above code but still the same ... when the xml does not conform against the XSD it does not log any error. :-(

Comment: Try add .setBody(constant("<test>123</test>")) before validation just for test. Is it still without error ?

Comment: Why you use "validator:file" ? Look at the documentation, it is "validator:someLocalOrRemoteResource"

Comment: :On doing "validator:someLocalOrRemoteResource" i.e. `.to("validator:src/main/resources/SampleXMLStructure.xsd")` it gives me **Cannot find resource: src/main/resources/SampleXMLStructure.xsd in classpath for URI: src/main/resources/SampleXMLStructure.xsd**

Comment: So move SampleXMLStructure.xsd to your jar